# Why is my code capitalizing words when I have specified not to?

Tags: ruby

```
class Book
    # write your code here
        attr_accessor :title

        def title= (title)

          @title = title.split()
          @title = @title.map {
              |x|
              index = @title.index(x)
               if x == 'and' or x == 'in' or x == 'of' or x == 'the' or x == 'a' or x == 'an' and index != 0

                x = x       
              else
                x.capitalize
              end
          }
          @title = @title.join(" ")
          return @title
        end              
    end
```

This is an exercise from the Project Ruby on the Odin Project. It's about capitalizing the titles of a book bound to some certain conditions life if the word is a preposition or an article or a conjunction then dont capitalize it unless it occurs in the beginning of the title then capitalize it. I have written the code for it but it isn't working as you can see :

```
index = @title.index(x)
if x == 'and' or x == 'in' or x == 'of' or x == 'the' or x == 'a' or x == 'an' and index != 0
  x = x
else 
  x.capitalize
end
```

But again it doesn't work

```
expected: "The Man in the Iron Mask"
got: "The Man in The Iron Mask"
```

The second `The` gets capitalized too when I have said in the `if` statement that if it isn't equal to the first word then don't capitalize it but it still capitalizes it.

Comment: You should start with a description of the problem you are trying to solve. You have provide that description, but in the wrong place. As it stands, some readers, me included, will try to figure out what you are seeking to do by studying your code. That's a waste of time...

Comment: ...You should give at least one example. Whenever you give an example you should assign a variable to each input, so that readers can refer to the variable in comments and answers without have do define it (e.g., `str = "a cat and the hat"`). You should also give the desired result for the example (e.g., `"A Cat and the Hat"`).

Answer (score 4):

Because `index(x)` always returns the first match.

I would rewrite it like this:

```
class Book    
  attr_accessor :title

  DO_NOT_CAPITALIZE = %w[and in of the a an]

  def title=(title)
    words = title.split.map do |word|
      # capitalize all word that are not excluded
      DO_NOT_CAPITALIZE.include?(word) ? word : word.capitalize
    end

    # always capitalize the first word
    @title = words.join(' ').capitalize
  end              
end
```

Comment: Alternately, you can use `with_index` to get the _correct_ index: `title.split.map.with_index { |word, index| index.nonzero? && DO_NOT_CAPITALIZE.include?(word) ? word : word.capitalize }.join(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code has been identified. One way to obtain the desired result is to use [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a simple regular expression.

```
LITTLE_WORDS = %w| a an and in of the |
  #=> ["a", "an", "and", "in", "of", "the"] 
LWR = /\b#{LITTLE_WORDS.join('|')}\b/i
  #=> /\ba|an|and|in|of|the\b/i
```

```
def normalize(str)
  str.gsub(/\S+/) do |word|
    if Regexp.last_match.begin(0).zero?
      word.capitalize
    else
      word.match?(LWR) ? word.downcase : word.capitalize
    end
  end
end
```

```
normalize("tHe cat and    A hAt")
  #=> "The Cat and    a Hat"
```

See [Regexp::last_match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match) (same as the value of the global variable `$~`) and [MatchData#begin](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/MatchData.html#method-i-begin). Notice that this preserves spacing in the string.

In the publishing industry such articles, prepositions and conjunctions are often referred to as "little words", and written <sub><sup><sub><sup>"a", "an", "and", "in", "of", "the"</sup></sub></sup></sub>.